# Live update of TreeView while populating in background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, treeview

Topic says it all , here it is code i have right now :

```
    public void StartCDA()
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    public delegate void AddCDAnode(DirectoryInfo dirinfo);

    public void ListDirectory(DirectoryInfo path)
    {
        ImagesTV.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(path));
    }

    public void Addnode(DirectoryInfo dirinfo)
    {
        Invoke(new AddCDAnode(ListDirectory), new object[] {dirinfo});
    }

    private TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {
        var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);
        foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            Statustext = directory.FullName;
            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
        }
        foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
        return directoryNode;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Addnode(CdaDir);
    }
```

Right now problem is that actually Treeview is not being populated in background and that's pretty strange as i am using background worker for that. But the main problem is that here i have kind of image viewer (form is splitted in two parts, left is treeview and right is picture preview box) and list of images to view sometime contains about 1000 elements , that's why i need to be able to see "live" update of treeview , while being able to go through items and view images. There will be no ability to delete , move or somehow affect Treeview , the only action is to click through tree.
Thanks.

Comment: I really suggest you use WPF for this one... Otherwise just implement an event handler for when the changes occur and update (maybe you have to invalidate - my winforms is a little rusty).

Comment: The thing is that this is only one module of whole application i have..And it is completely done in WinForms.

Comment: Actually seems that i can use WPF to create this module. Is that correct ?

Comment: Honestly, no clue... I believe there is in fact some interop, though i'v never had to use it, so i'm afraid i wouldn't be much help... [Here's a related quetion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/89d69566-e01d-4f3f-b974-48c6e395bee1/how-to-use-wpf-in-windows-forms).

Comment: To be clear:  are you saying that the `TreeNode` you get back from `CreateDirectoryNode` has no child nodes?  It appears to be recursive...is there a race?

Comment: I have tested this code and it seems to work fine. If all the information is right (i.e., backgroundWorker1_DoWork associated to the DoWork event, valid CdaDir, etc.), it should work. Can you please do a step-by-step execution to tell exactly what is going on (where it crashes or where it does/doesn't reach)?

Comment: Yes, the code is working fine , maybe i was misleading in my ask explanation. The thing is that i want to update TreeView as each element is being added by 10 elements for example to see them appearing by group of 10. And also i would like to add possibility to track which directory is being processed and possibility to cancel the process , with list of nodes which were added before the cancel. It is recursive because these are files\folders structure i am scanning.

Comment: You are asking for too much (and not too related with your original post). As you have your code now, you can do these things more or less easily, for example: this.label1.Text = directory.FullName.ToString(); The elements in the treeview are being updated/shown without any problem (at least in my computer and by testing a not-too-big sample). You can set a button with backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync(); ( backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true; and a condition existing the function on the lines of if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending) return;).

Comment: Actually that was exactly what i asked in original post and it is related to it. I need live update of TreeView nodes while being able to iterate through them. Thanks for a tip about cancelling.

Comment: http://grab.by/q9g0 this is how form looks, while background worker is being in action. And it is not accessible at all.

Comment: With this code?!On my computer looks nice (and I have provoked and endless loop to populate the treeview). Perhaps the problem is provoked by the list of images. Perhaps you should update your question (with the code of the list of images) to get quicker help on this front.

Comment: Yep, with this code. I completely turned off all of the events, leaving only this code to work on form load, and still this behaves like it is not working in another thread.. Maybe background worker is the problem , should i try Thread class ?

Comment: Thread class gives the same result.. It is not working in background, the form freezes while collecting nodes

Comment: varocarbas : can you please share the solution or just code where this part of code is working ? i've made new project and tested this code in it - it is not working in background. Thanks !

Comment: Sorry I didn't get any of your previous messages (you have to put @ before the nicknme). I did test exactly this code and I created an infinite loop populating nodes which worked fine. Apparently you are using the GUI thread too much (with the images) and this is why it does not work well with you. I have seen your new question and the answer you got there what makes lots of sense: don't mix up GUI with non-GUI parts. For example: intead of adding the nodes directly to the GUI, add them to a global treeview and pass their elements every certain (there is where you should invoke the GUI)

Comment: Understand your code: when you do Invoke(new AddCDAnode(ListDirectory), new object[] {dirinfo}); you use the GUI thread (otherwise you wouldn't be able to affect controls from the Form) and thus the "backgroundworker advantage" is lost. Remove this part and let the backgroundworker deal just with the loop (and, as suggested, stored it in a TreeView variable) and don't make the calls to change the treeview so regular. There is no straightforward solution: just work from your side (and a proper understanding of what is going on).

Comment: PS: I don't need to write the @ because I am writing in an answer created by you.